# How do I bypass Zeplin API rate limit error

Tags: node.js, rate-limiting, zeplin

I'm using [Zeplin API](https://docs.zeplin.dev/reference#introduction) to automatically generate the colours, typography and components defined on Zeplin and include them into a project, but according to the [official documentation](https://docs.zeplin.dev/reference#rate-limiting), there is a **200 limit requests per minute**. Everything was working properly when there were a few components, but now I have several projects defined on Zeplin, and I'm getting an HTTP rate limiting error (429).

Has anyone faced this issue? Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The limits aren't there to be broken. That would be a violation of Zeplin's terms of service.

Comment: If you are in a free plan, I guess you can pay for the service to remove the rate limit.
If you are already on a paid plan, I think you should contact their support team.

Comment: Thanks @germanio, I'll check that.